# I made this little calculator, but it isn't showing the output

Tags: php, html

It isnt showing output, it refreshes but result isn't showing. i wonder what i'm doing wrong?
I just want the output shown in the same page, below the submit button it should be centered as well, but it aint working, kindly help me out guys, Thanks.

```
<html>
<head></head
<body>
    <form method="post" align="center">
        <input type="text" name="FirstValue" placeholder="Enter First Number"><br>
        <input type="text" name="Operator" placeholder="Enter Operator / * + -"><br>
        <input type="text" name="SecondValue" placeholder="Enter Second Number"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br><br>
    </form>
    
    <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                
                $N1 = $_POST['FirstValue'];
                $OP = $_POST['Operator'];
                $N2 = $_POST['SecondValue'];
                
                
                switch($OP){
                        
                    case '/':
                    echo "Division Result = ".$N1/$N2;
                    break;
                    
                    case '*':
                    echo "Multiplication Result = ".$N1*$N2;
                    break;
                        
                    case '+':
                    echo "Addition Result = ".$N1+$N2;
                    break;
                        
                    case '-':
                    echo "Subtraction Result = ".$N1-$N2;
                    break;
                    
                    default:
                    echo "Invalid Option";
                }
                    return 0;
                }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try with () in the operations, like:  echo "Subtraction Result = ".($N1-$N2);

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` – never true, because you have no form field by that name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `name="submit"`. Full html form:

```
        <form method="post" align="center">
    <input type="text" name="FirstValue" placeholder="Enter First Number"><br>
    <input type="text" name="Operator" placeholder="Enter Operator / * + -"><br>
    <input type="text" name="SecondValue" placeholder="Enter Second Number"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Oh god, i went crazy, wondering what could be wrong. i didn't realize, Thanks a lot.

Comment: If it helped then please mark my answer as solution.
You are welcome @ZealFied :)

Answer (score -1):

In a real example you need to sanitize inputs before using or echoing to display.
Or you can check numbers $N1 and $N2 with function is_numeric before calculating or using as feedback to user.